# JSON String with elements containing unescaped double quotes

Tags: python, regex, json

While trying to parse JSON from an AJAX request, the string returned contains invalid JSON.

Although the best practice would be to change the server to reply with valid JSON, as suggested in multiple related answers, this is not an option.

Trying to solve this problem using python, I looked at regular expressions.

The main problem is elements as follows (which I currently use as a test string:

```
testStr = '{"KEY1":"THIS IS "AN" ELEMENT","KEY2":"""THIS IS ANOTHER "ELEMENT""}'
```

I currently use the following code:

```
jsonString = re.sub(r'(?<=\w)\"(?=[^\(\:\}\,])','\\"',testStr)
jsonString = re.sub(r'\"\"(?![,}:])','\"\\\"',jsonString)
```

with very limited success.

If I was using C, I would parse the string, and simply escape all double quotes within the element (i.e between all double quotes which are preceded by [:{},] )

There must be a pythonic way to parse, without resorting to a for loop and looking ahead, and keeping history.

EDIT:

Assuming that strings do not contain: [ : { } ]
And also assuming that the unescaped double quotes are only within the value, and not in the key,
Then I assume that the following (or something similar should solve the problem:

```
 import re
 re.sub(r'(?<![\[\:])\"(?![,\}),'\"',testString)
```

But it still does not work.

Comment: This is non-determinant ... there will be situations where you cannot know whether a `"` is a delimiter or part of a value ... :0(

Comment: I understand, what if strings never contain "[ : { } ," ? Is it still non-determinant.

Comment: If strings never have `,` then it should be possible, but it seems like this is still going to be a case of looking ahead because you need to know that a `,` follows a `"` ... if your JSON always has `,` immediately after `"` then the look ahead can be done with a single character ... if there could be whitespace after the `"`, then you will obviously have to work harder!!

Comment: Reading  https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax "Group references are not supported even if they match strings of some fixed length" Could this be the reason my (edited) solution does not work?

Comment: The "right" way to do this is to write your own JSON parser.  Which is really hard.

Comment: @Jack, assuming all I have to do is parse the JSON string and escape all double quotes that aren't preceded by a double colon, and aren't succeeded by '}' or ',' , and then parse the (repaired) string through the JSON parser in json. This should be easier.

Comment: Why is it not possible to get the buggy non-JSON producer code fixed?  It is ridiculous to have a broken program spewing forth bilious pseudo-JSON and not attempt to get it fixed.

Comment: I'm with @JonathanLeffler. *Why* it is not an option to change the server? I don't mean that I don't get this - I've worked for companies before where I've also entered such situations. But hey! These are bad practices! Of course the server has to be fixed! We should not advertise anything else here. If you need support for this, send the persons who'll decide it a link to this discussion.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler
It's not my server, and I am not affiliated in any way with it. I am clean-room reverse engineering a client (That as you can imagine based on the server) is **very** buggy, and I need to make a new one for my use.

Comment: EDIT: I also do not want to "peek" at the android/java code by decompiling - in case there are legal issues.

Comment: Another example of "why" is that the Spotify public API outputs broken JSON in this way. I can complain to Spotify and hope they fix it, but in the mean time I'd like my script to work.

Answer (score 3):

Seems I needed a break to solve this.

The following regular expression seems to replace only doublequotes that are contained within the element string. (With the assumptions I stated in the question)

```
output = re.sub(r'(?<![\[\:\{\,])\"(?![\:\}\,])','\\\"', stringName)
```

I have created a sandbox here: https://repl.it/vNK

Example Output:

```
Original String:
{"KEY1":"THIS IS "AN" ELEMENT","KEY2":"""THIS IS ANOTHER "ELEMENT""}

Modified String:
{"KEY1":"THIS IS \"AN\" ELEMENT","KEY2":"\"\"THIS IS ANOTHER \"ELEMENT\""}

Parsed JSON:
{
    "KEY1": "THIS IS \"AN\" ELEMENT",
    "KEY2": "\"\"THIS IS ANOTHER \"ELEMENT\""
}
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: This has saved me from an awful situation (fixing JSON incorrectly stored in a postgres json column as an array with one long escaped JSON string in it).  Some of the encoded strings included doublequotes and it nearly broke me. For any other lost souls, https://regex101.com will help explain how this magical, magical regex works.

Comment: I should have got back to you as soon as I saw your comment. It turns out I was decoding UTF in python before decoding the JSON. When the UTF was decoded, extra doublequotes appeared (the encoded ones) and the JSON decoder complained. This was fixed by decoding JSON _first_ and then the actual data. (D' OH!)